# Print 3 rows on the same line dynamically

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Currently, I have a table that prints one entry per row.

**Sector**: Technology
**FullTimeEmployees**:  352600
**MarketCapitalization**:   110921621504
**ERatio**: 14.0941
**PEGRatio**:   8.6659
**BookValue**:  23.076

However, I would like to print 3 rows on the same line dynamically, so that the final result looks like this

> **Sector**:   Technology            **FullTimeEmployees**:    352600        **MarketCapitalization**: 110921621504
> **PERatio**:  14.0941  **PEGRatio**:  8.6659                 **BookValue**:   23.076

I was wondering if it's possible to achieve this result with tables or should I try using the list?

```js
import React from 'react';
import '../CSS/GenInfo.css'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';



// redux syntax that is used to access props from the store object
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        geninfo: state.updateSidebar.info.data
    }
}


class GenInfo extends React.Component {

    renderTableHeader() {
    }

    renderTableData() {
        var items = this.props.geninfo[1];
        const listItems = Object.keys(items).map((key) =>
            <tbody key={key}>
                <tr>
                    <td>{key}</td>
                    <td>{items[key]}</td>
                </tr>  
            </tbody>      
        );
        return (
            listItems
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div class='GenInfoComp'>
                <table id="t01" >
                     {this.renderTableData()}
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GenInfo);
```

Comment: I can help you if you can replicate your output through https://codesandbox.io/s/ or something similar?

Comment: Thank you for the offer! I just ended up using a list, worked just fine.